# SQL Server stored procedure EAN code validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, stored-procedures, ean-13

I need to write a stored procedure or funtion to validate the insert of EAN13 code in SQL Server.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What you tried so far? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting questions

Comment: What do you mean by *inclusion*? And also: validate ***how*** ? Lookup against a set of valid values? Not quite clear....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved,

I created a function for validation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [sp_ean](@Ean varchar(max)) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Factor INT
    DECLARE @Sum INT
    DECLARE @Len INT
    DECLARE @CC INT
    DECLARE @CA INT
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Len = LEN(@Ean)
    SET @Sum = 0
    SET @Factor = 3

    IF @Len = 14 OR @Len = 13 OR @Len = 12 OR @Len = 8 
        BEGIN
            WHILE @Len > 0 
                BEGIN
                    IF @Len  13
                        BEGIN
                            SET @Sum = @Sum + SUBSTRING(@Ean,@Len,1) * @Factor
                            SET @Factor = 4 - @Factor
                        END
                    SET @Len = @Len - 1
                END

            SET @CC = ((1000 - @Sum) % 10)
            SET @CA = SUBSTRING(@Ean,LEN(@Ean),1)

            IF  @CC = @CA
                BEGIN
                    SET @Result = 0
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @Result = 1
                END
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 1
        END
    RETURN (@Result)
    END
```

Result:
**0** to **true** or **1** to **false**

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to mention that EAN13 is a very common code used to identify products at checkout counters.

Comment: What do you mean with "IF @Len  13"??

Comment: meaning "IF @Len = 13"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll find something like this to be cleaner. It handles the variable length input and also has the advantage of being usable as a check constraint as pointed out by [Joe Celko](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic508572-1305-1.aspx).

```
CASE WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean), 1, 1) AS INTEGER) =
        10 - (
               3 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 2, 1)) AS INT)
               1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 3, 1)) AS INT)
               3 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 4, 1)) AS INT)
               1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 5, 1)) AS INT)
               3 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 6, 1)) AS INT)
               1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 7, 1)) AS INT)
               3 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 8, 1)) AS INT)
               1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 9, 1)) AS INT)
               3 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 10, 1)) AS INT)
               1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 11, 1)) AS INT)
               3 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 12, 1)) AS INT)
               1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 13, 1)) AS INT)
               3 * CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ean) + '000000', 14, 1)) AS INT)
             ) % 10
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```